# Como almacenar un List<Object> en Session asp net core 3

Tags: c#, api, lista, asp.net-core

Soy un poco nuevo en la creacion de API, quiero crear una variable de sesion y guardar una lista de un objeto "List<PRECIOS_CLIENTES>" para hacer uso de esta en otra operacion,

```
public class PRECIOS_CLIENTES
    {
        public string numero_parte { get; set; }
        public string causa_precio { get; set; }
        public string po { get; set; }
        public decimal precio { get; set; }
        public string moneda { get; set; }
        public decimal diferencia { get; set; }
        public string estatus { get; set; }
        public decimal old_price { get; set; }
    }
```

pero aquí me tira este error;
"CS0308 El método 'ISession.Set(string,byte[])' no genérico no se puede usar con argumentos de tipo", al hacerlo de esta manera:

```
List<PRECIOS_CLIENTES> l_precios = new List<PRECIOS_CLIENTES>();

HttpContext.Session.Set<List<PRECIOS_CLIENTES>>("nombre", l_precios);
```

Como puedo hacer esto en .net Core 3 o de que otra manera puedo manejar esta información?

Comment: Lo que tiene que hacer es serializar el List<object> con NewtonSoft y de esa manera poder guardarlo como un string.

Comment: "Me tira error"... Alfredo, cuál error? Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el texto del error. @RichardVíquezPérez, por qué utilizar NewtonSoft, cuando NetCore tiene el namespace [System.Text.Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.0) para serializar sin necesitar de una librería/paquete externa?

Comment: Gracias @Arriel, ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: @Arriel Bueno yo creo que eso ya es cuestión de gustos. Se puede usar cualquiera de los 2 pero personalmente prefiero el NewtonSoft.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias hacer la serialización de la lista usando Newtonsoft.Json, y utilizar el método SetString, en lugar del Set, te quedaría así:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("nombre",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l_precios));
```